# Rate of lost to follow-up at first year

Tags: r, sas, survival

Is this the correct way to calculate the rate of lost to follow-up at first year?

Rate of lost to follow-up at first year= rate of censored subjects at firstyear.

There is no specific method for that calculation in SAS or R. Am I correct?

Comment: Hello, I'm afraid this question contains very little information and seems to assume specific domain knowledge (i.e. that we would definitely know what "lost to follow-up at first year" means in the context of your individual problem).  Can you please expand on your question a bit?